# cURL вывести параметры POST запроса

Tags: php, curl

Через cURL пытаюсь отправить файл на сервер, но возникает какая-то ошибка.
Проблема 100% в запросе, так как через web интерфейс все прекрасно работает.
Как можно вывести весь запрос что делает cURL?
Делаю сейчас так:

```
$f = fopen('D:\\request.txt', 'w');
$headers = array(); 
$headers[] = "Content-Type:multipart/form-data";
$headers[] = "Cookie:".$_COOKIE["cookie"];
$headers[] = 'Host:localhost';

$postfields = array("files[]" => "@$filedata", "requesttoken" => $_COOKIE["token"]);
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
    CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
```

Но в фаиле только хедеры, а post-параметров нету.

**UPDATE** Заливаю фаил на облако (написано на php), в результате запроса возвращается json в котором есть `"message":"No file was uploaded. Unknown error"`

**UPDATE2** Если из браузера скопировать запрос что делает веб-форма то будет такое

```
 curl "http://localhost/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php" 
-H "Cookie: ocmu36tgg12w=f1qtl9f38hkrnpojo6eel5h685;" 
-H "requesttoken: 209ef67fc8f7a577bf9d" 
-H "Origin: http://localhost" 
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" 
-H "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" 
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36       (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36 OPR/31.0.1889.99" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHAeOzi7oWQcAwTix" 
-H "Accept: */*" 
-H "Referer: http://localhost/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/" 
-H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 
-H "Connection: keep-alive" 

--data-binary 
"------WebKitFormBoundaryHAeOzi7oWQcAwTix"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""requesttoken"""^

"------WebKitFormBoundaryHAeOzi7oWQcAwTix"^
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""files[]""; filename=""123.PNG"""^
"Content-Type: image/png"^


"------WebKitFormBoundaryHAeOzi7oWQcAwTix--"^
"" --compressed
```

сама форма

```
    <div id="upload" class="button" original-title="Загрузка (Максимум: 513 MB)">
                <input type="hidden" id="max_upload" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="537919488" original-title="">
                <input type="hidden" id="upload_limit" value="537919488" original-title="">
                <input type="hidden" id="free_space" value="281326030848" original-title="">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="max_human_file_size" value="(max )" original-title="">
                <input type="file" id="file_upload_start" name="files[]" data-url="/owncloud/index.php/apps/files/ajax/upload.php" original-title="" multiple="multiple">
                <a href="#" class="svg icon-upload"></a>
   </div>
```

**UPDATE3** 
через сниффер посмотрел на запрос
в моем в параметрах:

```
--------------------------bcc584d42b4ad159
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"
@D:\me\htdocs\lab6\2.PNG
```

а в веб-форме :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryRUZKjLJ4eNBcy1CP  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="123.PNG"  
Content-Type: image/png  
и далее фаил в бинарном виде
```

Comment: `curl_error($ch);` в студию

Comment: @ArchDemon, `curl_error($ch);` ничего не возвращает, если сделать `echo json_encode(curl_getinfo($ch));` то там стоит 200 в статусе запроса

Comment: Вы так попробуйте if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

Comment: Код формы отправки файла из вэб интерфейса покажите.

Comment: @Visman, обновил. Но это только html, в части js там запутанно

Comment: Что в массивах $_FILES и $_POST при отправке через curl?

Comment: @Visman, дополнил вопрос. Оказывается я не все параметры отправляю. Как с помощью cURL можно отправить в таком виде как в UPDATE3 в самом конце?

Comment: Curl автоматически должен считать при наличии @, что вы передаете файл. Как вы переменную $filedata задаете?

Comment: @Visman, `$filedata =  'D:\\me\\htdocs\\lab6\\'.$uploadfile;`  где uploadfile это имя файла. Фаил существует в данной папке

Comment: У вас версия PHP какая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что у вас проблема с массивом `files`, введенным для мульти-загрузки. Попробуйте заменить

```
$postfields = array("files[]" => "@$filedata", "requesttoken" => $_COOKIE["token"]);
```

на

```
$postfields = array("files[0]" => "@$filedata", "requesttoken" => $_COOKIE["token"]);
```

**UPD**

Из комментариев и уточнений выяснилось, что curl не воспринимает передаваемые в скрипте данные как файл. Тут я могу сделать предположение, вы используете версию PHP 5.6 или выше. Предположение от сюда проистекает:

> С версии PHP 5.5.0, префикс @ устарел и файлы можно отправлять с помощью CURLFile.

Источник http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

> In 5.6, @ option will be switched off by default,

Исчтоник https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

Решение: заменить

```
$postfields = array("files[]" => "@$filedata", "requesttoken" => $_COOKIE["token"]);
```

на

```
$postfields = array("files[]" => new CurlFile($filedata, 'image/png'), "requesttoken" => $_COOKIE["token"]);
```

Тип файла как второй параметр можно опустить.