# Нужно отправить файл через form

Tags: php

Нужно отправить файл через форму на сайте.
Сделать надо через php, то есть:

1. Создается файл
2. Скрипт php передает его через form на другом сайте
3. На этом работа кода заканчивается

Можно ли так вообще реализовать и как?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443513/186083

Comment: curl тебе в помощь

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$target="http://youraddress.tld/example/upload.php";

// Create a CURLFile object / procedural method 
$cfile = curl_file_create('resource/test.png','image/png','testpic'); // try adding 

// Assign POST data
$imgdata = array('myimage' => $cfile);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // stop verifying certificate
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // enable posting
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $imgdata); // post images 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // if any redirection after upload
$r = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php